# How to invoke a Convenience Initialiser on UIView when a view is loaded using loadNibNamed ?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, swift3

How can I invoke a convenience initialiser of a view loaded from .xib file?
I have initialiser defined as below:

```
class CustomView : UIView{
    var prop1:Int
    var prop2:Int
    convenience init(prop1:Int, prop2:Int, frame:CGRect){
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }
}
```

Now, how can I get this initialiser executed if I want to instantiate the customView from its associated .xib file like this

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomView
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you load from xib then you call `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`

Comment: Short answer; you can't. Set the properties after you create the view or specify them in the nib and use the init(coder) as Adrian suggested

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulw said, you can't. Views loaded from xib/storyboard are always initialized with `init(coder:)`. The [UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview) states:

> Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using
>   their init(coder:​) method, which modifies the attributes of the view
>   to match the attributes stored in the nib file.

If you want to set up your custom view in Interface Builder, and you have custom properties you want to set, you can make those properties `IBInspectable`.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var prop1: Int
    @IBInspectable var prop2: Int

}
```

Then, you'll see them in the Attributes inspector when you select that view in Interface Builder (make sure to set the Class to the name of your class in the Identity inspector first).

[image: Interface Builder Attributes Inspector showing IBInspectable properties]

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com) has a great article on IBInspectable [here](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/).